# How to control Spark application per task/stage/job attempt?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'd like to stop Spark from retrying a Spark application in case some particular exception is thrown. I only want to limit the number of retries in case certain conditions are met. Otherwise, I want default number of retries.

Note that there is only one Spark job which a Spark application runs.

I tried setting `javaSparkContext.setLocalProperty("spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts", "1");`  in the case of the exception, but it still retries the whole job.

I submit the Spark application as follows:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster theSparkApp.jar
```

I have a use case where I want to delete the output if it is created by the previous retry of the same job, but fail the job if the output folder is not empty (in 1st retry). Can you think of any other way to achieve this?

Comment: How do you submit your Spark application for deployment? What are the command-line options and Spark properties in use? BTW, even when you said you meant "the entire Spark application", you still used "the whole job is still retried". One Spark application can run/submit one or many Spark jobs.

Comment: Can you please use `spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1` instead (and use the Spark setting on command line).

Answer (score 1):

> I have a use case where I want to delete the output if it is created by the previous retry of the same job, but fail the job if the output folder is not empty (in 1st retry). Can you think of any other way to achieve this ?

You can use [TaskContext](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.TaskContext) to control how your Spark job behaves given, say, the number of retries as follows:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(0 to 8, numSlices = 1)

import org.apache.spark.TaskContext

def businessCondition(ctx: TaskContext): Boolean = {
  ctx.attemptNumber == 0
}

val mapped = rdd.map { n =>
  val ctx = TaskContext.get
  if (businessCondition(ctx)) {
    println("Failing the task because business condition is met")
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("attemptNumber == 0")
  }
  println(s"It's ok to proceed -- business condition is NOT met")
  n
}
mapped.count
```

Comment: The issue here is that I don't know whether my job failed the first retry due to businessCondition() or due to some other reason (unless I maintain this state somewhere outside of Spark, which I want to avoid). So the only possible way I can think of is to force Spark failure without any retry in case the businessCondition() is met.

Comment: What about `addTaskCompletionListener(listener: TaskCompletionListener): TaskContext` and `addTaskFailureListener(listener: TaskFailureListener): TaskContext`? Never used them before, but they look as if they might help here.

Comment: `onApplicationEnd` could have worked, but there is no way to get TaskContext in SparkListener. I need TaskContext to figure out what exactly to delete. Also, I'm not sure if it is possible to find if the application succeeded or failed in the listener interface.